# Twitter for software development (java)?

Tags: java, twitter

I'm wondering if [twitter](http://twitter.com/) is of any use to stay up to date with themes of current software development activities. Primarily I'm interested in java.

Are there any tweets that you would recommend?

Comment: Sorry, this is offtopic (not a programming problem), but this is a perfect subject for http://programmers.stackexchange.com. Try it over there :)

Comment: Try @developerworks and @sunmicrosystems. Not posting as answer because it's a pretty poor suggestion, but both tend to have a fair number of Java-related tweets.

Comment: The FAQ says this site is for questions of `matters that are unique to the programming profession`. I think this description matches my question very well.

Comment: It's however subjective/argumentative and that falls then in the other category :)

Comment: OK, I made it community wiki. That should make it acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an eye on the following tags #java #openjdk and #java7

Follow @jodastephen, @Jazoon, @javaposse, @coderanch, @java7developer, @AdamBien, @java and the list goes on, but you'll start to see who else who'll want to follow in their streams.

disclaimer:  I'm affiliated with @java7developer and @coderanch

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, search for '#java', this yields lots of job offers, but some more interesting java stuff as well.